# How to access files from network path on .net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, virtual-directory

I want to access files from a networkpath (\172.x.x.x\I$).The files should not be served staticly, they should only be accessisble through code.

When accessing a file directly I get an UnauthorizedAccessException: access to path denied.

What are my options here? Adding a virtual directory seems like a good idea here. But I'm stuck trying to access the virtual directory from .net core(3.1).

Comment: Are you using IIS? Does the user (under which the application runs) have read permissions to the network drive? Don't confuse your local access rights with access rights from IIS.

Comment: the `\172.x.x.x\I$` shared path is accessible using evaluated permissions only. Please try to run your code as admin. However I do not think that assigning admin user permissions to the IIS app pool is a good idea (since question is tagged with `asp.net-core`)

Comment: Yes I'm using IIS. The application user does not have read permissions. But I would prefer to use a virtual directory. Is that an option in .net core?
Admin rights seems like a bad Idea for securityreasons?

Comment: [Virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) does not allow you to read the hidden shares I suppose but please try

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772997/cant-access-to-network-share-from-application/56802141#56802141) discussed a similar issue, you can check it.