# Create file from IIS Manager to Virtual Disk (Share Folder)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-8

I have a problem here. I have implemented a web application ASP.NET MVC to IIS Manager. When the web app runs, it will create a file (.txt) to the virtual disk (share folder), but it throws an error that can not find the virtual disk (share folder). I don't have experience with implement web apps and IIS Manager, so I hope everyone can help me with this problem!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What "share folder"? You have to describe in accurate words (such as mapped drives), or share screen shots to illustrate clearly. IIS does not support mapped drives in all kinds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean the shared folder is a network location (ex:  Y:\  or P:\) as you called mapped drivers as well.

Comment: Then you cannot use that in any IIS settings or web apps. Microsoft removed KB257174 for no clear reason, but there are other posts over the internet talking about mapped drives and UNC paths, https://west-wind.com/wconnect/weblog/ShowEntry.blog?id=911

Comment: As far as i know, the virtual disk is based on the current user account. Since the application pool identity is another user, it couldn't see the virtual disk. I suggest you use share folder instead of using virtual disk. about how to use the share folder you can refer to this link:[share folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772997/cant-access-to-network-share-from-application/56802141#56802141).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me!

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Has not been resolved yet! I've tried but... Thanks for asking!